# Using newman in jenkins through powershell or windows batch command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, newman

I am looking to run the following link

```
cd c:\Users\Testing
newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/abcrtetv345692ty99aer12 -e c:\postman\environment\Env2.postman_environment.json
```

and I am getting following error in jenkins:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Newman is a javascript application intended to run on node.js. You need to install node.js and ensure that `node.exe` is in your path.

Download windows installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ - and install it on your jenkins slave (or master if it's a single machine install).

**EDIT:** Make sure that node.exe is in the path of the user, under which Jenkins executes, not just your user.

Comment: I do have nodejs installed on my pc and it's mentioned in the path aswell

Comment: In path of what user?  If it's present in the path of your user, it doesn't mean it's present in the path of the jenkins user.